# Error creating foreign key in MySql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create relation between two tables. My table names are `employees` and `salaries`. I tried the following code:

```
ALTER TABLE `salaries` 
ADD FOREIGN KEY (`eid`) 
REFERENCES `employees`(`id`) 
ON DELETE CASCADE 
ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

But it shows an error:

> Error creating foreign key on eid (check data types)

**employees table structure:**

```
+---------------------------------------+
| id           | int(11)      | primary |
|--------------+--------------+---------|
| name         | varchar(255) | unique  |
|--------------+--------------+---------|
| basic        | int(11)      |         |
|--------------+--------------+---------|
| ot_rate      | int(11)      |         |
|--------------+--------------+---------|
| joining_date | date         |         |
+---------------------------------------+
```

**salaries Table Structure:**

```
+---------------------------------------+
| id           | int(11)      | primary |
|--------------+--------------+---------|
| eid          | int(11)      | index   | <-- I want to create foreign key on this column with employees->id.
|--------------+--------------+---------|
| month        | varchar(255) |         |
|--------------+--------------+---------|
| date         | date         |         |
|--------------+--------------+---------|
| working_day  | int(11)      |         |
+--------------+--------------+---------+
| ot_hour      | int(11)      |         |
|--------------+--------------+---------|
| ot_amount    | int(11)      |         |
|--------------+--------------+---------|
| basic_amount | int(11)      |         |
|--------------+--------------+---------|
| tatal_salary | inf(11)      |         |
|--------------+--------------+---------|
| comment      | varchar(255) |         |
+---------------------------------------+
```

I tried changing `eid`'s data type to `varchar`,`tinyint`,`text` etc. All has the same error message.

**UPDATE**

After using this:

```
ALTER TABLE `salaries` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `salary` FOREIGN KEY (`eid`) 
REFERENCES `employees`(`id`) 
ON DELETE CASCADE 
ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

I am having this error message:

```
#1005 - Can't create table `zamzam`.`#sql-14b4_1a5` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
```

Comment: Do you have another table with a foreign key to that same column?

Comment: No, I don't have any foreign key in whole database.

Comment: Do the two tables use the same storage engine?

Comment: Both tables Storage Engine is `InnoDB`, Collation is `utf8_general_ci` and ROW_FORMAT is `COMPACT`

Comment: I'm running out of ideas. But there are many other questions about the same error here. Use the search field, go through each of them, and see if any of them have a fix that works for you.

Comment: That will be easier than me going through them, and then asking you a question for each different reason.

Comment: I saw them and even tried some. But same error for me.

Comment: please post your table creation queries

Answer (score 0):

Have you used the relational view option in the table to create the foreign key contraint .
    this link will show you the way -http://www.binarytides.com/create-foreign-key-phpmyadmin/
    thanks

Comment: I did, it shows the same error. Now I have another error message. I updated my question. Please, consider review my question.